# Retrieve text blocks from file

Tags: python, file-io

In a file I've blocks of queries separated by blank lines (can be one or more blank lines). Is there a better way to get the queries into a list ?

Ex File:

```
select * from tbA
where colA= '2'

select * from tbB
where colB = 'c'
order by colc



select * from tbC
```

Code I've so far:

```
queries = list()
with open(sql_file_path, 'rb') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    i = 0
    while i < len(lines):
        query = ''
        while i < len(lines) and not lines[i].isspace():
            query += lines[i]
            i += 1
        while i < len(lines) and lines[i].isspace():
            i += 1
        queries.append(query.strip())
```

The result I'm looking for is a list containing the complete queries not just one line of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(path) as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f if line]
```

The list comp will iterate through your file line by line and build it into the list if the line is not blank. If it is blank, it will ignore it.

As per your edited text, just split on a blank line (that is, `\n\n`).

```
with open(path) as f:
    lines = [query for query in f.read().split("\n\n") if query]
```

You could also do it by regex:

```
import re

with open(path) as f:
    queries = re.split(r"\n\n+",f.read())
```

Comment: i don't want a list of non-empty lines, I want a list of complete queries. I've updated the question with a better example.

Comment: @ziddarth edited. This is much uglier, but should do the trick.

Comment: +1 If lines are blank, but not empty, you can use the `split()` provided by the `re` (regex) module

Comment: Thanks! I got it. Had to adjust for line feed \r.

Comment: @ziddarth oh duh, sorry I missed that. I think there's a better way for that...let me look real quick...yes, use `os.linesep`

Answer (score 0):

```
queries = [query.strip() for query in re.split(r"(\r\n)(\r\n)+", all_text, ) if query.strip()]
```