# Split string with double enter in Python

Tags: python

I have something like that:

```
1    
2      
3

4    
5     
6
```

And I want it to have :

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

How can I do it? Thanks a lot

Comment: possible dupe of [Retrieve text blocks from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895907/retrieve-text-blocks-from-file/21895925?noredirect=1#comment33167927_21895925), although this title is much nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
input = '''1    
2      
3

4    
5     
6'''

def parse(string):
    out = []
    groups = string.split('\n\n') # Split by empty line
    for group in groups:
        out.append([item.strip() for item in group.split('\n')])
    return out

print(parse(input))
```

Answer (score 3):

With list comprehension

```
import os
src = """1
2
3

4
5
6"""

print [[int(x) for x in sub.split(os.linesep)] for sub in src.split(os.linesep*2)]


#special case if this is for windows and src is a string
print [[int(x) for x in sub.split('\n')] for sub in src.split('\n\n')]
```

would return

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Whoops, you got it right and we had the same approach, so I deleted my answer. May want to include the note about `os.linesep` only working from file (for instance, your code returns a `ValueError` for me since I'm on windows and there are no `\r\n` in src

Comment: For unix, there is also a plain `\n` as a newline character. You might have this problem, when you read text files, which were edited with windows text editors, but in general `\n` should work on most machines.